# Is it possible to get Ajax response in next code line after request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Juvenile question, i know.
But is there any possible way to make Ajax call in the middle of the function and then work with the response in The Same Function?

There is no any simple solution, but if you can suggest any complex one it would be very nice of you.

Codesample:

```
function getSomeAjax(){ 
    var params = prepareRequestParams();
    //do some ajax magic here and get ajaxResponseData
    return ajaxResponseData;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it? I mean, what's wrong with CPS style?

Comment: @penartur i have older colleague who really love his current function structure and dont want to listn to any Async needs. So i dont want to write complete alien and serching for possible pretty solution for unpretty code. Thats sad.

Comment: He needs to accept that the browser UI is an event driven environment and adjust his coding style to fit. :)

Comment: @eugene_selivonchyk If he also loves his current bicycle, it doesn't mean you should modify your car with workarounds so that he could pedal instead of pushing the gas pedal. User interface must be async, full stop. As an argument, ask your colleague whether he wants for PC to completely lock up while the browser is loading some page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without getting rid of the A in Ajax. You could use a synchronous request instead of an asynchronous request (set the third argument of [`xhr.open()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method) to `false`), but that locks up all JS processing until the response comes back, so is a terrible idea.

Just use a callback method.

Comment: thats exactly the same what i was thinking about. But i really needed to hear it from the third party. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback function for it:

```
function test(){
    //ajaxcall here, with a callback function to callback()
}

function callback(){
    // do the thing you want here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention if you want to use synch. or synch. calling.
Using asynch. could cause that you will get answer from server after you will try to return ajaxReponseData, so using synch. calling would be easiest way.

I have to warn you of course, that sync. calling of Ajax can cause client browser to freeze while waiting on answer so you should rethink the design if think that you have to use sync. version.